# How can one draw an ASCII right triangle?

Tags: java

Whats wrong with this code??
it doesnt seem to print out much of anything

```
public void RTriangle(char appearance, int size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(appearance);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: At what point are you appending whitespace?  There are two characters being used here - ` ` and `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void print(final char appearance, final int size){
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = size - i; j >0; j--)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for (int k = i; k > 0; k--)
            System.out.print(appearance);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

That should do as directed. Tell me if you want me to explain the logic.

Comment: I'd *love* for you to explain the logic.

Comment: Explanation would be great

Comment: I did it as relate-able to the real world as I could. You start with i being 1, to signify first row. From there, you can clearly see it goes for the amount of rows for the size. You then start with the size, subtracting the row count (row one has one star, row two has two). You keep counting down till you are at 0 left to be printed. From there, you repeat the same for the stars counting your way down  until you don't have to print any more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got to have your indices right. For example:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) { // count of rows
    for (int j = 0 ; j < size ; j++)
      System.out.print ((i < j) ? " " : appearance);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void RTriangle(char appearance, int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if((size-j)<i) // the amount of * depents on i and it goes from the right to the left so use size -j
                System.out.print(""+appearance); //""+ turns the char into a string
        }
        System.out.println(); //append a line when your first line is done
    }
}
```